# Join a series of values in different rows into one

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I need to do an ETL job and I have a table that looks like this

```
user_name | role
----------+------
User A    | Admin
User A    | System
User B    | Editor
User B    | Power User
User B    | System
```

I want to transform that into

```
user_name | role
----------+------
User A    | Admin, System
User B    | Editor, Power User, System
```

I thought about creating temp tables and using `row_number() over (partition by user_name)` but it started to get messy. Is there a better way to get that output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the aggregate function [**`string_agg()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html).

```
SELECT user_name, string_agg("role", ', ') AS roles
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

If you want the list in alphabetical order:

```
string_agg("role", ', ' ORDER BY "role")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_name, 
 array_to_string(array(
        select role
        from my_table
        where user_name =m.user_name
        order by user_name
        ), ', '
    ) combined_rows
from my_table m

group by 1
```

Link to [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/42ecf/1)